# Holepunching of header in magento store

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, full-page-cache, holepunching

I have implemented hole-punching of header in Magento, and even though I have got it working on a per-customer basis, I need the ability to take this one level deeper by making it work on diff cart items counts too.

Here is my code.

```
    class AD_PageCache_Model_Container_Header extends Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Abstract {

    protected function _getIdentifier() {
        return $this->_getCookieValue(Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cookie::COOKIE_CUSTOMER, '');
    }

    // public function getCacheKeyInfo() {
    //  $info = parent::getCacheKeyInfo();
    //  die('boo');
    //  $info['cart_count'] = Mage::helper( 'checkout/cart' )->getCart()->getItemsCount();

    //  return $info;
    // }

    protected function _getCacheId() {
        //return 'CONTAINER_HEADER_' . md5($this->_placeholder->getAttribute('cache_id') . $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('cart_count') ) . '_' . $this->_getIdentifier();
        return 'CONTAINER_HEADER_' . md5( $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('cache_id') . $this->_getIdentifier() );
    }

    protected function _renderBlock() {
        $blockClass = $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('block');
        $template = $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('template');

        $block = new $blockClass;
        $block->setTemplate($template);
        return $block->toHtml();
    }

}
```

My understanding from what I have been reading from hole-punching threads on Magento is that the Mage app is not initialized when the FPC cache is serving the request, so basically, the method of adding a placeholder attribute can't work, since

> `Mage::helper( 'checkout/cart' )->getCart()->getItemsCount();`

won't work, right?

And even though how is that it should be, but it didn't seem to run at all like I placed a `die()` call in there but nothing happened.

So what I am missing? And how can I retrieve the cart items count so that it can be used to build the cache ID?

Progress: I found

> `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cookie::COOKIE_CART`

but this changes only once upon cart updation. After that, it stays the same. This is weird, this feels like the solution but its behavior says otherwise.

I couldn't find cart items count in session either. So the only way I currently see to do this would be to save the cart quantity in session whenever it updates and then uses that in `_getIdentifier()`.

I found that observers are inconsistent with the cart. In addition, updation the events are dispatched but for removal, it doesn't. So I guess I can add my observer to price updation of the quote somehow if that is consistent in having observers?

Also, I did read  [Full Page Cache invalidation on the cart (quote) change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802663/full-page-cache-invalidation-on-cart-quote-change) but it handles using

> `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cookie::COOKIE_CART`

which doesn't work well in my case, although I think the problem lies inside it. What/How? I am not sure.

> Also the current version of EE we have running doesn't even have
> Advanced folder under `Model/Container`. I am using `EE 1.10.1.1`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure, but I think that this question is more related to Stack Overflow, but not this site...

Comment: Holepunching seems to be used here in a non traditional sense, can you explain the feature you're trying to implement without using jargon?

Comment: Why not append the customers cart id to `_getIdentifier` so the block is unique to customers cart, or even the number of items in their cart?

Comment: @SergeiGuk Well it's heavily related to Magento

Comment: @RalphTice I'm trying to implement a cart value indicator in the header which shows the user how many items they have in their cart. Since that value is different per user, I don't want it to be cached.

Answer (score 3):

Using `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cookie::COOKIE_CART` is the right way to go, but you may need to do some changes.

`Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Observer::registerQuoteChange` is called on every quote save (item number change included) and it is also called in the context on `Mage::app()` so you can access all session data. Overwrite this observer and add more data in `$this->_getCookie()->setObscure` so the value changes whenever you need to.

Comment: Any examples you might be willing to share on doing this?